# How to run C++ with QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, configuration, cmake

I'm trying to use cmake to run c++ using QT creator. I downloaded cmake, created a new project, clicked on the project configuration button, clicked on manage kits, click on the cmake tab, and then pressed add and added the path to my cmake.exe `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe`. Afterwards strange things started to happen. It keeps saying `configuration failed` so I went back to my build settings and under the build directory, it's listing out a path that doesn't exist. Why is that happening? In the compile output, it says

```
Starting: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --target all
Error while building/deploying project icg (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "CMake Build"
```

Here's the contents of my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(icg)

#--- Load the common ICG configuration
include(common/config.cmake)
include(common/Eigen.cmake)
include(common/OpenGP.cmake)

#--- OpenGL configuration
include(common/OpenGL.cmake)
include(common/GLEW.cmake)
include(common/GLFW.cmake)

#--- Subprojects
add_subdirectory(transform)
add_subdirectory(mouse)
```

This file is in the root of the directory. The particular project I'm trying to run is called transform which also has a CMakeLists.txt file in the transform directory.

```
get_filename_component(EXERCISENAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} NAME)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SHADERS "*.glsl")
add_executable(${EXERCISENAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${SHADERS})
target_link_libraries(${EXERCISENAME} ${COMMON_LIBS})
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

Comment: There is a tab in Qt Creator that shows the cmake output which probably includes useful information for why the configuration failed.

Comment: The only tab that's giving me output is the compile output tab. That tab says "Starting: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --target all
Error while building/deploying project icg (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "CMake Build". But I don't know what that means.

Comment: You probably have the “General Messages” tab disabled. CMake details appear there. Try Alt+7 to open it.

Comment: It's not disabled. I do see things when I'm scanning and configuring the project but it doesn't show any errors. The compile errors tab shows an error at step "Cmake Build." I was able to get the build directory sorted out by messing around with the kits and now the correct folder was created but I still can't run it though. I was able to create a new hello world c++ file and run that but when I opened up an existing project with a CMakeLists.txt file it wouldn't work. The thing is I was able to get this project running on a Mac machine but I can't get it to run on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator doesn't always create the build directory if it doesn't exist when you first define the project. Instead, it silently uses a temporary directory until you actually create the build directory yourself. This is not what developers normally expect and is probably a bug, but that is the behaviour you are currently observing. If you manually create the build directory and re-run CMake, Creator should then be using the correct directories and I'd expect it to build (unless your project has other errors in its CMakeLists.txt files, obviously).

To make the `General Messages` tab appear if it isn't showing for you at the moment, click the up-down button at the end of the list of output panes at the bottom of the window and enable it in the pop-up that appears:

[image: Output panes]

You can also do this through the *Window* --> *Output Panes* menu.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything on the general messages tab when I compile and run it. It configures the project and then it just says "generating done" and doesn't say anything else when I try to run it. Then the compile output says there was a problem during the step "CMake Build" and the application output says that transform.exe does not exist. I'm sure there's no problem with the CMakeLists.txt since I was able to run this on another computer. The other computer was a Mac and mine is a Windows but I don't think that should cause problems. Could it be the version that I'm using?

Comment: Also I messed around with the kits in QT creator and that seemed to fix the configuration error but now there's the problem running an existing project. I can show you the CMakeLists text document I'm using just in case there's a problem with that.

Comment: Yes, add the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` file to the question as an update. That might reveal the build part of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Ok I added the txt file.

Comment: Can we move discussion to [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145293/question-44220730) temporarily to do a bit of investigation? I'll remove these comments when we've got it all resolved.